# Building node-sqlite3 with nw-gyp

Tags: node.js, sqlite, node-webkit

I am trying to build sqlite3 for a node-webkit.

The [sqlite3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3#installing) page explains that it needs to be done with with nw-gyp

As far as I understand it, I should download the [source](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3) locally and then navigate to the src folder and run this ([shown here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3#installing)):

```
npm install sqlite3 --build-from-source --runtime=node-webkit --target_arch=ia32 --target=$(NODE_WEBKIT_VERSION)
```

Thing is, whatever location I run that command, I get these errors:

- npm WARN package.json sqlite3@3.0.10 No licence field.
- npm WARN install Refusing to install sqlite3 as a dependency of itself
- npm WARN node-pre-gyp was bundled with sqlite3@3.0.10, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree.

Maybe I am doing this totally wrong, I just don't know :)

NW-gyp version: V0.12.4
Node-webkit version: 0.12.3

OS: Windows 7

I made small step toward the success, but not yet there. It seems that I should try that command in empty folder. So I did, but I have loads of errors now.

The very first error is:

ERROR: Empty target version is not supported if node-webkit is the target. Then it is followed with many STACK errors.

The first stack one is: at get_node_webkit_abi (full path of the file) utils/versioning.js

MORE Updates:
This command removed many errors:

```
 npm install sqlite3 --build-from-source --runtime=node-webkit --target_arch=ia32 --target=0.12.3
```

Then there was error that Pything can't be found. That is fixed. Still more error, now with C++ compilers. I think I have complete mess with NET redistributables.

Next error in line is:
 error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code -1073741515

This is the error I am getting now:
[image]

More improvements. I am getting error: undefined variable module_name in binding.gyp
[image]

Next steps I did:

- I installed npm install -g node-pre-gyp
- Than I run node-pre-gyp rebuild --runtime=node-webkit --target=0.12.3
- That gave me error missing nan module missing
- I installed it
- And I am getting the same screen as in first screenshot (MSB6006).

Answer (score 4):

I managed to build using the following commands on mac:

```
sudo npm install nw-gyp -g
npm install sqlite3 --build-from-source --runtime=node-webkit --target_arch=ia32 --target=0.12.3
```

First, make sure you installed `nw-gyp` globally. Then, run the command either in the directory containing node-webkit executables (nwjs), or in a subfolder of that folder.

Running the command should then create a `node_modules` folder in the same directory as the binaries, containing the `sqlite3` module.

Comment: That I got working with Vanilla Node.js. But for node-webkit, I must compile it.

Comment: I tried that as well, but the result is the same. I have updated my original question.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me to build sqlite3 for Windows 7:

1. Follow these steps: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/629#issuecomment-138276692
2. Run your node.js command prompt
3. Call Setenv.cmd from this solution: https://gist.github.com/kosmobot/6020327

You can download the module itself from Google Drive using this link: /open?id=0B20fPv1V1FfuMFhKLXdHOXNOR28

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but how Do I download the module from the google drive usaing the provided id? :)

Comment: Here is the full link: [node_modules.zip](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B20fPv1V1FfuMFhKLXdHOXNOR28)